# Greplace.vim not loading buffers

Tags: vim, buffer

I'm attempting to use [Greplace](https://github.com/skwp/greplace.vim) for project wide find and replace but am having trouble in the final steps.

I start with:

`:Gsearch mypattern *`

Which successfully opens a buffer that lists all the files and the matches. I then perform:

`:%s/mypattern/newpattern/g`

Which replaces all the instances within the Gsearch buffer. It's now that I have trouble, when I perform:

`Greplace`

I am now prompted whether I want to make the changes, to which I answer with `y`. At which point each file should be loading in a buffer, changes made and ready for me to `:wall`, but that never happens. The Gsearch buffer remains, no others load and no changes have been made to any file.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker. [This](https://github.com/skwp/greplace.vim/issues) is an issue tracker.

Comment: @ingo-karkat I'm not reporting an issue on SU, I'm asking for help _using_ a vim plugin.

Comment: If it's not clear from the plugin's documentation how to use it, the author is probably interested, too, and in the best position to help with it, anyway. And your description sounds like its a bug in the plugin.